# Can I build a single, bulk SQL update command

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I’d like to do a bulk update to a RDBMS table (from within a Java program via JDBC), but I’m not sure how to achieve it without writing an UPDATE statement for every record.

Here’s a rough outline of the issue. I have a table called SUBS with the following columns and sample data:

```
ID (int), Type(bool), D1 (date), D2 (date), D3 (date)
1000, 1, 2013-08-31, 2013-10-31, 2013-10-31
1001, 0, 2013-10-31, NULL, NULL
1002, 0, 2013-11-30, NULL, NULL
…
```

Depending on the Type being 0 or 1, I either want to update D1 only, or D2 and D3. In my program, I have a data structure including the IDs, the type and the desired new dates (D1-D3). I can easily iterate over this data structure and generate the following commands:

```
UPDATE SUBS SET D2 = “2014-01-31”, D3 = ‘2014-01-31’ WHERE ID = 1000
UPDATE SUBS SET D1 = “2013-12-31” WHERE ID = 1001
UPDATE SUBS SET D1 = “2014-01-31” WHERE ID = 1002
```

However, is there a way to do this in a single SQL command? Or maybe two commands, one for each Type (0 or 1)?

Comment: where do the dates come from in your update statements?

Comment: The dates are calculated within the Java program. I'll edit the question to clarify.

Comment: [Sounds like you're boned](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jdbcteam/archive/2012/04/03/how-would-you-use-table-valued-parameters-tvp.aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your new data is called NEWSUBS, and has the same table structure, then I think something this is what you're after:

```
UPDATE S SET 
    D1 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 0 THEN N.D1 ELSE S.D1 END,
    D2 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 1 THEN N.D2 ELSE S.D2 END,
    D3 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 1 THEN N.D3 ELSE S.D3 END
FROM    SUBS S
JOIN    NEWSUBS N
    ON  N.ID = S.ID
    AND N.[Type] = S.[Type]
```

Basically it just updates SUBS WITH the current value (i.e. no change) for the columns that should be unnafected

Given that your data is local, as per the comment, the only other way I can see would be to build up an xml parameter and pass that through to do the update, something like this:

```
DECLARE @NEWSUBSXML xml

SELECT @NEWSUBSXML = '
<SUBS>
    <SUB>
        <ID>1000</ID>
        <TYPE>1</TYPE>
        <D>2014-01-31</D>
    </SUB>
    <SUB>
        <ID>1001</ID>
        <TYPE>0</TYPE>
        <D>2013-12-31</D>
    </SUB>
    <SUB>
        <ID>1002</ID>
        <TYPE>0</TYPE>
        <D>2014-01-31</D>
    </SUB>
</SUBS>' 



UPDATE S SET 
    D1 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 0 THEN N.D ELSE S.D1 END,
    D2 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 1 THEN N.D ELSE S.D2 END,
    D3 = CASE N.[Type] WHEN 1 THEN N.D ELSE S.D3 END
FROM    SUBS S
JOIN    
(       SELECT  ParamValues.ID.value('(ID)[1]','INT') AS [ID],
                ParamValues.ID.value('(TYPE)[1]','INT') AS [Type],
                ParamValues.ID.value('(D)[1]','DATE') AS [D]
        FROM    @NEWSUBSXML.nodes('/SUBS/SUB') as ParamValues(ID) 
) N
    ON  N.ID = S.ID
    AND N.[Type] = S.[Type]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I understand how it works. Unfortunately my new data is in a data structure within my (Java) program. So I think such a JOIN is out of the question in this case.

Comment: Well, in that case, I would bulk upload the data from your data structure to a temp table in the database, and then join to that temp table...

Comment: added alternative that takes xml input (assuming you could convert your local data structure to xml?) and uses that for a bulk join/update

Comment: There is no simple update - either you keep the data on the client and do multiple single row updates as you are doing, or you send all of the data in one hit and do a single multiple row update.  The only way I can see to do that is to parcel the data up in xml as per the updated response

Comment: OK, that answers my question I think. The XML solution is certainly possible as I could easily convert my data to such a structure. I might stick with multiple UPDATE statements as that looks quicker and easier and performance is not a major issue. However, I'll definitely try the XML solution if I have time.